# How to change data table column names dynamically using interop excel in c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RBox.jpg

Above image shows what i want, i wish to remove prefix part all columns names like ,WK1-600,WK1-700,WK1-800....WK2-600,WK2-700,WK2-800....WK3-600,WK3-700,WK4-800....WK4-600,WK4-700,WK4-800 etc then remove 600, 700, 800 alternately.

I am trying below code but i dont know how to fix it correclty in interop excel... i am very jr in coding please help me....big thanks in advance

```
foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {

                string colname = column.ColumnName;

                if (colname == "Retailer" || colname == "Brand") ;

                else
                {

                    ds.Tables[0].Columns[colname].ColumnName = "WK" + colname.split('-')[0];

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to remove "WK" from column names. Is it correct?
If that's your intention sample below will help

```
void Main()
{
//init. table 
System.Data.DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {new DataColumn("Retailer"),
new DataColumn("Brand"),
new DataColumn("WK1-600"),
new DataColumn("WK2-700"),new DataColumn("WK3-800")});

//go over columns and rename
foreach (DataColumn dc in tbl.Columns)
{
    if(dc.ColumnName.Contains("WK")){
        dc.ColumnName = dc.ColumnName.Split('-')[1];
    }
}

//verifiyng the result
  foreach (DataColumn dc in tbl.Columns)
  {

        Console.WriteLine(dc.ColumnName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...but if i wish to remove all numbers in column names, which placing after ('-'), then what will i do?...can you please help

Comment: just replace  dc.ColumnName = dc.ColumnName.Split('-')[1]; with  dc.ColumnName = dc.ColumnName.Split('-')[0]; Names will be "WK1", "WK2", etc.